# Rails, Capistrano, Nginx, Unicorn - Application has been already initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn, capistrano3

I followed ChuckJHardy [example](https://gist.github.com/ChuckJHardy/f44dda5f94c6bbdba9a4) on how to deploy a rails app to a VPS using Capistrano, Nginx, Unicorn. The deployment process passed from my local machine but my rails application is not loading fine. I am getting the following errors
[image]

I checked the log from my unicorn.rb log and I see the bellow errors.

Please help me with some Idea's I am totally confuse.

```
I, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.183042 #7200]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.197960 #7200] ERROR -- : error reloading config_file=/home/deploy/apps/onozor/current/config/unicorn/production.rb: Application has been already initialized. (RuntimeError)
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198056 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.6/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize!'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198095 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198142 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/releases/20161023193809/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198165 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198199 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198233 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198260 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198295 #7200] ERROR -- : config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198315 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198340 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198373 #7200] ERROR -- : config.ru:1:in `new'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198393 #7200] ERROR -- : config.ru:1:in `<main>'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198444 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn.rb:56:in `eval'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198496 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn.rb:56:in `block in builder'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198518 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:752:in `build_app!'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198552 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:733:in `load_config!'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198590 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:314:in `join'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198616 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198648 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198669 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/apps/onozor/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198686 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198738 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198762 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198806 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
E, [2016-10-23T19:40:36.198862 #7200] ERROR -- : /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
```